# Client-Side MVC: how to best handle same templates in different engines

Tags: haml, client-side, erb, handlebars.js, mustache

I've been recently experimenting with one of the widely recommended MVC client-side frameworks (Backbone, in this case). I find it quite nice, but I have an issue with it: suppose I'm building a list of contents, which I want to present on browsers using client-side rendering, but also want to make available for search engines, which do not run javascript. That means, I'll also have to render stuff on the server-side. Now, let's say I'm using Handlebars.js, whose template language is inherited from mustache. All is well. But on the server, I'm using ERB (or HAML, whatever). That means, I'll have to support more than one version of the same template. Which is just unmaintainable, for cases where your templates going beyond the list-element 4 lines of code. How are the big platforms working around this issue?